# How to make the function accept a block

Tags: ruby

I am having a class G and my custom function func which i expect to take a block like this:

```
class G
def func(&block)
return '1' unless block_given?
# More code
end
end
```

I think that now when i do

```
G g = new G
g.func {|t| t}
```

block_given? should return true but its returning false

I hve tried following variants as well to no resort

```
g.func do |t|
end
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Works fine for me, although I'm not sure what language your test block is written in--in Ruby it'd be `g = G.new`.

Comment: Dave, yep, me too. I think that is some kind of misunderstanding because of using 'unless' instead of 'if'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's working fine if you correct some minor syntax errors. Note that there is no type declaration for ruby variables and object instantiation is done through an instance method of class `Class` instead with keyword (like in Java):

```
class G
  def func(&block)
    return '1' unless block_given?
    block.call
  end
end

g = G.new
g.func { puts 'block was called' }
g.func
# Output:
# irb(main):046:0>g.func { puts 'block was called' }
# block was called
# => nil
# irb(main):047:0>g.func
# => "1"
```

Comment: Minor nitpick: `new` is actually an instance method of class `Class`. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Class.html#method-i-new (meaning `G.new` isn't a class method of `G`, but an instance method of the instance `G` of class `Class`).

Comment: Since we are nitpicking anyway: there is no such thing as a *class method* in Ruby. Class methods are just singleton methods of the class object. Oh, wait, there's no such thing as a *singleton method*, either :-) Singleton methods are just regular old boring instance methods of the singleton class.

Answer (score 0):

(Adding my output, although Matt beat me to it.)

```
> class G
>   def func(&block)
>     return '1' unless block_given?
>     # More code
>   end
> end
=> nil 
> g = G.new
=> #<G:0x856e444> 
> g.func { |t| puts "hi" }
=> nil 
> g.func
=> "1"
```